# REACT: How can you tell which variable is causing componentDidUpdate() to be fired?

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-component

I noticed that my component (parent component) updates twice after being initialized and I'm trying to figure out what is causing this. Is there a way to see which state variable is responsible for componentDidUpdate being fired?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here's some context - After a user logs into my site, they get re-routed to a dashboard that has 3 HTML canvas components that don't have any custom child components (only react bootstrap components). When the user get re-routed, componentDidUpdate() gets called (as expected). However, shortly after the initial call, componentDidUpdate() gets called again (even without interacting with any of the canvases, or making any changes).

I'm trying to initialize the canvases on the second round of the componentDidUpdate() call, because the clientHeight of the canvas I'm trying to init is only accurate after this second call. After the first componentDidUpdate() call, the clientHeight is returning a values that's larger than it should be.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible snippet?

Comment: React's devtools can show you why a component updated. It could also be React Scrict Mode refiring things twice.

Comment: I added some context to the ticket description. Hope that helps clarify things!